# Ruby on Rails Routing Error

Tags: ubuntu, path, ruby, rails

I am running ruby on rails on an Ubuntu Droplet and I am encountering the following error when I navigate to my domain name:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant HomeController
Rails.root: /home/rails/example

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes
Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper      HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url     GET       /         home#index
root_path
```

I have tried running

```
rails g controller home index
```

But I get an extensive error. These are the first few lines of the error:

```
/home/rails/example/config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <main>': undefined local 
variable or method `map' for # . 
<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00007f11683c6fd8> 
Did you mean? tap (NameError) 
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack- 
5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec' 
from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack- 
5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
```

This is the relevant file tree:

```
app
  -controllers
    -application_controller.rb
bin
config
  -routes.rb
```

These are the contents of application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

These are the contents of routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'home#index'


 Place at the end of the routing!
map.root :controller => 'MyController', :action => :index

end
```

Comment: Is there a constant "HomeController" in your code? I.e. in `/home/rails/example/...`. Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Do you mean the error log?

Comment: @rudib can we open this in a chat?

Comment: You must have a class `HomeController` defined somewhere in the code. Probably under `./controllers/home_controller.rb` or similar.

Comment: No. There is not HomeController there.

Comment: I can show you in chat.

Comment: Could you update your question with how you application is set up and provide th e relevant parts of your code? Also, could you provide the "extensive error"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84104/discussion-between-cody-rutscher-and-rudib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the routes are pointing to non existing controllers.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
#root to: 'home#index'


# Place at the end of the routing!
#map.root :controller => 'MyController', :action => :index

end
```

Commenting them out should get the command working again.